# UIImageView memory increases when changing image first time

Tags: memory-management, swift3, uiimageview, image-size

A Demo Project -

I have an UIImageView and three buttons.

Whenever I have clicked any of button, I am changing image of the image view. My images are of 1242*1242 in size.

Problem: Every first when I have clicked the button it took memory 5 MB. For example, I have clicked button 1, memory increase by 5 MB and then I have pressed button 2, memory increases by 5 MB. But when I have clicked button 1 again no memory increased.

**Is this usual behavior of UIImage View?** Actually, I am working on Photo Frames and each time when I have applied new frame memory is increased. Due to this after applying 30-40 frames app crashes.

**Can someone refer how to work on such type of photo frame apps or any reason why is UIImagesView taking memory?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes @Amanpreet, I am also getting the same behavior. While investigating in the instrument I found that some chunk of memory as **ImageIO-jpeg-data** allocating every time I load a new image on button click.

**---------------------SOLUTION-----------------------------**

Load image in imageView with

`UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath!)`

method. And now your memory size will not increase every time with new image.

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
@IBAction func loadOne(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "jpg")
    imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
}

@IBAction func loadTwo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "2", ofType: "jpg")
    imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

}

@IBAction func loadThree(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "3", ofType: "jpg")
    imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
}
```

i am using images of size 1920*1280 , Previously my memory usage increases like *41.6 MB*,
*51.5 MB*,
*59.5 MB*,
*67.5 MB*, after every click, But after adopting solution given above memory usage stucks at *50.4 MB*

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help :)